# Java Saving ArrayList error

Tags: java, arraylist, save

Hello this is my code eclipse is telling me the hire `ArrayList` needs to be an `int` and I want to print the `toString()` method in hire class so I can print everything in the array

```
    public static void save() {
    try {

        File file = new File("D:/Assignment/filename.txt");

        // If file does not exists then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(Hire hire:HireList)
        bw.write(hire);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write the `hire.toString()`, simply use this :

```
bw.write(hire.toStrig());
```

else Javac can't know if your calling `bw.write(int)`or `bw.write(String)` or other ...